# Xubuntu 13.04 some images won't load properly in any browser

Tags: nvidia, kernel, firefox, xubuntu, google-chrome

I've had this problem for a couple of days now and I have no clue what might be causing it. When entering a particular website, it won't load the same images over and over again. At first I thought it was a problem with Chrome, but I it's the same with Firefox and Chromium.

This is how I see my subscriptions feed in YouTube:
[image]

And this is how I see Chrome's Web Store:
[image]

I've tried the following things so far without any success:

- I've deleted the cache of FF and Chrome numerous times
- Reinstalled Chrome a couple of times and even switched versions (from 26.0.1410.43 to 28.0.1500.71)
- I've tried 'Empty cache and Hard Reload' from the context menu of the Refresh button in Chrome when the F12 key is pressed.
- Even deleting the browsers' folders from ~/.cache won't do the trick. The same images won't load every time.
- I completely reinstalled my Xubuntu and in the beginning there wasn't such a problem. However, after an hour or so (after I finished installing my stuff), it appeared again. In Windows I don't have such an issue with the same Google account(s).
- Incognito Mode doesn't help.
- Disabling all extensions;
- Disabling Pepper Flash and enabling Shockwave Flash from chrome://plugins;
- Reinstalling Java OpenJDK 7

Due to the fact that a forum post suggested it might be a graphics driver issue (although regarding an AMD card), I thought it may have something to do with my new gpu. A few weeks back I used Intel HD Graphics but can't confirm that the problem didn't occur then. Now I have a GTX 760, using the 319.32 version of Nvidia's drivers. Could this be related somehow?
Some people having similar issues suggested it might be a problem with the kernel (3.8.0-26-generic). However, a fresh install of Xubuntu 13.04 has a 3.8.0-19-generic kernel and after installing the updates, you can choose between -19 and -26. My gpu's drivers are installed for the -26 kernel and when launching the -19 (without gpu drivers installed) the problem persists.
Other people stated it might be a conflict with xfce, but God, I can't stand the newer versions of Gnome.
I don't know what to do, please help - it's driving me insane.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: No. Nor system, neither browser. By the way, I forgot to mention that some people on the Google support pages regarded this as an ISP issue but I'm not sure that's possible. Others said it was due to a connection to a Wi-Fi network. Although I don't use wi-fi to connect to the internet with my PC, I disabled it from my router but still, no use.

Answer (score 1):

Oh my God, I just resolved the issue. It was due to a couple of iptables rules which were meant for anti-exploit protection of a gameserver I'm hosting but it seems that some of them interfere with my browser experience... I'm going to look for a security workaround, at least now the pages load properly.